# IE hanging on js errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript, simplemodal

The page hangs for a long time in IE but Chrome/FF power right through it.

Here's the page in question http://174.120.239.48/~peakperf/

=============

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Timestamp: Mon, 7 Mar 2011 21:18:49 UTC

Message: Not implemented

Line: 432
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://174.120.239.48/~peakperf/wp-content/themes/strausberg/js/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.1.js

==========

Here's the pastebin of the js: 
http://pastebin.com/xXaCK6XH

Here's the js in question:
http://174.120.239.48/~peakperf/wp-content/themes/strausberg/js/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.1.js

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure any Javascript (jQuery) that manipulates the DOM happens in the [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event of the `document`.

In several places in your HTML, you're modifying the DOM right when the script tag gets parsed. Now, if you look in the IE dev toolbar, you'll notice the following:

```
SCRIPT16385: Not implemented

jquery.simplemodal-1.4.1.js, line 432 character 7
LOG: [cycle] DOM not ready, queuing slideshow 
LOG: [cycle] DOM not ready, queuing slideshow 
LOG: [cycle] DOM not ready, queuing slideshow 
LOG: [cycle] terminating; too few slides: 0 
LOG: [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector
```

I think the offending Javascript is:

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".basic").modal({overlayClose:true});
</script>
```

Which should be changed to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".basic").modal({overlayClose:true});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If I add the doc.ready function the modal pops up on page load which is the incorrect behavior. I'd like the link to open a modal on mouse click. Of course it works fine in FF and chrome but not IE.

Answer (score 1):

This website says that function (`removeExpression`) is not supported by IE8 as it is deprecated: http://help.dottoro.com/ljuvxilu.php

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue, was using a reserved JS word and IE was throwing this error. :| Hope it helps!